# ASP response to a formatted html table instead of JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a hyperlink that runs an asp sample below;

```
cgroup_histstatus.aspx?Staging_PKID=24648
```

It is getting the right results and displays it on the browser. However it comes in a JSON string format like below:

```
{  
  "custgroup": [
      {
        "datetime": "12/8/2016 4:40:03 PM",
        "card": "0000000025000001997",
        "status": "Removed"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "12/8/2016 4:40:03 PM",
        "card": "0000000047005095855",
        "status": "Removed"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "12/8/2016 4:40:03 PM",
        "card": "0000000250000012997",
        "status": "Removed"
      }
    ],
    "success": true
 }
```

How can I add on the asp code to format it to a html table instead of just plain JSON above. Currently the asp is only doing below for the output.

```
Response.Write(jsonResponse.ToString());
```

Comment: Did you do any research or try anything.  It doesn't take much to google for it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800664/how-to-read-json-and-display-in-html-table-in-c

Comment: So take a JSON string and inserting table elements is not working?  Please post what you have tried.

Comment: You could loop through the results and use JavaScript to create elements and place them on the page where you want them. Or you could use some sort of templating library to generate the appropriate HTML. It's really up to you, it's simple enough that even someone new to HTML and JS can figure it out with a couple web searches.

Answer (score -1):

You have to have some sort of HTML element on your page to display your results. Since the data look like tabular results, you would probably want a table on your aspx page. Then, in your server side code, instead of "echoing" the results to the response, you would bind the data to your table. You should be able to look up how do bind your data to a table on your aspx page.